# Always start Spring Boot Server

Tags: spring-boot

If an error occurs during startup, e.g. wrong database password, the server will not start. But if you use spring actuator, the server could return DOWN on the health interface, instead of not starting the server.

Is it possible to start the server despite errors and then display the error via /health?

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little bit about what are you trying to achieve using this `/health` point when there are errors which can't allow the server to run?

Comment: There are errors that the healh check verifies e.g. is there a valid database connection. However, if such an error occurs during startup, the entire server will not start. It would actually be more comfortable that the health resource is available. The status of the database is down and you know you have a issue.

In a Cloud environment with kubernrtes in use, the operating would be more convenient than looking into the logs for this error.